# Manual entry on dropdown form field

Tags: yii2

I have a form with a dropdown field which lists several location names. But I want to have an "other" option and when users select it, they can fill it with location name that isn't included in the list.

Answer (score 0):

The good news is that [selectize.js](http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/) does exactly it.

> Selectize is the hybrid of a textbox and box. It's jQuery-based and it's useful for tagging, contact lists, country selectors, and so on.

Comment: Just checked it. Is it different from [select2](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2)?